# Is it possible to check if a value exists inside an array full of objects without looping?

Tags: php, arrays, oop

I Have an array holding multiple objects. Is it posible to check if a value exists in any one of the objects e.g. id->27 **without looping**? In a similar fashion to PHP's in_array() function. Thanks.

```
> array(10)[0]=>Object #673 
                     ["id"]=>25 
                     ["name"]=>spiderman   
           [1]=>Object #674
                     ["id"]=>26
                     ["name"]=>superman   
           [2]=>Object #675
                     ["id"]=>27
                     ["name"]=>superman 
           ....... 
           .......
           .........
```

Comment: If you are asking if functional programming can be used to search for a property value in an array of objects, then the answer is yes, ...but it will never be as fast/efficient as using a classic loop with an early `return`/`break`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. If you often need quick direct lookup of values, you need to use array keys for them, which are lightning fast to lookup. For example:

```
// prepare once
$indexed = array();
foreach ($array as $object) {
    $indexed[$object->id] = $object;
}

// lookup often
if (isset($indexed[42])) {
    // object with id 42 exists...
}
```

If you need to lookup objects by different keys, so you can't really index them by one specific key, you need to look into different search strategies like [binary searches](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search).

Answer (score 5):

You will need to do looping one way or another - but you don't have to manually implement the loop yourself.  Have a look at [`array_filter` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php).  All you need to do is to provide a function that checks the objects, something like this:

```
function checkID($var)
{
    return $var->id == 27;
}

if(count(array_filter($input_array, "checkID"))) {
    // you have at least one matching element
}
```

Or you can even do this in one line:

```
if(count(array_filter($input_array, function($var) { return $var->id == 27; }))) {
    // you have at least one matching element
}
```

Comment: This is potentially very wasteful, since it does not break once the value is found, but always iterates through all of them.

Comment: @deceze Agree.  The question is how big is his array.  If he's dealing with millions of items, this will not be good.  If the array contains only a few items (even a few hundred), the impact will be negligible.

Comment: `empty` doesn't work on function return values, and there's no need to use it here anyway. A pure boolean comparison is just fine.

Comment: @deceze I know.  I'm not sure what happened there: I edited my post before, removing `empty` - but it re-appeared.  I edited again.

Comment: @AleksG Thanks for this solution. I noticed though that you're missing a closing ')' for the if statement in both snippets.

Comment: @InertialIgnorance Ah! Good catch, thanks, I updated/fixed it.

Answer (score 5):

```
$results = array_filter($array, function($item){
   return ($item->id === 27);
});
if ($results)
{
   ..  You have matches
}
```

Comment: Don't use `!empty($var)` when you just mean `$var`.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to combine two functions to get the desired results.

> array_search($needle, array_column($array, 'key_field');

Created a small code to demonstrate its use.

```
<?php
$superheroes    =    [
    [
        "id"    =>    1,
        "name"  =>    "spiderman"
    ],
    [
        "id"    =>    2,
        "name"  =>    "superman"
    ],
    [
        "id"    =>    3,
        "name"  =>    "batman"
    ],
    [
        "id"    =>    4,
        "name"  =>    "robin"
    ],
];
$needle    =    'spiderman';
$index     =    array_search($needle, array_column($superheroes, "name"));
echo "Is $needle a superhero?<br/>";


//Comparing it like this is important because if the element is found at index 0, 
//array_search will return 0 which means false. Hence compare it with !== operator
if ( false !== $index ) {
    echo "yes";
} else {
    echo "no";
}
?>
```

Comment: How's that an array full of objects?

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
foreach ($array as $value)
{
   if ($value == "what you are looking for")
       break;
}
```

Comment: you said without looping through entire array

Comment: Haha true. I will change appropriately.

Answer (score -1):

> [array_search](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) — Searches the array for a given value and returns the
>   corresponding key if successful

```
$key = array_search('your search', $array);
```

Comment: While it's a good function, it won't work for OP, because he needs to check a field in the array's values, not the value itself - and `array_search` doesn't accept comparison function